# Como traer el value del select con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

espero estén muy bien un saludo.

Como hago para traer el valor del value al seleccionarlo del select:

Ejemplo: este es mi select:

```
<tr>
<?php

   $sqlmate = "SELECT id_ppl,cliente,peligro,pasopp FROM para_peligros WHERE cliente='$acliente' AND pasopp='$pasoagre'";
   $resultmat=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlmate);

?>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Peligro:</font></td>  
    <td><select id="peligroppls" class="camp" style="width:200px;" required>
    <option></option> 
    <?php
    
    while ($rowma = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultmat))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$rowma['id_ppl']?>"><?=$rowma['peligro']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>  
    
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

Como ven en los option el llena automáticamente con los valores que encuentra en la consulta y en el select estoy mostrando una variable, pero como ven quiero llevar es el value del opción.

Y este es el JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('ready',function(){
    $('#peligroppls').on('change', function() {
      var peligroppls = $("#peligroppls option:selected" ).text();
      var dataString = 'peligroppls=' + peligroppls;
      
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "datapeli.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data)
           {
             $('#dano').html(data);
             
           }
         });

    });
  });
  </script>
```

El problema es que cuando dejo el option de esta forma:

```
<option value="<?=$rowma['peligro']?>"><?=$rowma['peligro']?></option>
```

Si me funciona bien el código.

Pero cuando quiero hacer lo que necesito:

```
<option value="<?=$rowma['id_ppl']?>"><?=$rowma['peligro']?></option>
```

Allí si no me funciona, de que forma puedo arreglarlo?

Cualquier ayuda me puede ser de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Inténtalo así var peligroppls = $(this).val(); ya que el "this" que esta dentro del evento change son las propiedades del select. El "val" es el valor que tiene el "option" actualmente seleccionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de lo que te decia en el comentario, espero sea lo que estes buscando

```js
$(function() {
    $("#peligroppls").on("change", function(){
      var variable = $(this).val();
      $("#selected").html(variable);
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="peligroppls" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected >Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Valor de la opcion seleccionada <span id="selected"></span>  </label>
```

Comment: Hola Alan, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funciono perfecto.